# How to get the text of a node before its first child node by xpath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

`<a>mytext<b>other</b><a>`

Suppose that I have the above XML data, I'd like to extract "mytext". But `//a` will retrieve both `mytext` and `other`. Is there a way to extract the text before the first child node of `<a>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These XPaths will select the `mytext` text node:

- All text node children of `a`: (There's only one.)

  ```
  /a/text()
  ```

  (Append `[1]` to specify only the first one.)
- All text node children of `a` before `b`: (There's only one.)

  ```
  /a/b/preceding-sibling::text()
  ```

  (Append `[1]` to specify only the first one back.)

Comment: What if the name of `b` is not known or could be anything? How to make the code robust when the internal node does not exist?

Comment: Both of those questions are answerable but merit their own, new questions.  Be sure to provide adequate markup examples to illustrate your needs regarding what can and cannot be assumed to be invariant.  Thanks.